# Android Upgrade Database File And Keep Data

Tags: android, database, persistence, upgrade

How can I upgrade the database which is stored in raw directory and also persist data? I create the database with this code:

```
public class DataBaseManager extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

// The Android's default system path of your application database.
//data/data/ and /databases remain the same always. The one that must be changed is com.example which represents
//the MAIN package of your project
private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.example/databases/";

//the name of your database
private static String DB_NAME = "database";

private static SQLiteDatabase mDataBase;

private static DataBaseManager sInstance = null;
// database version    
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

/**
 * Constructor Takes and keeps a reference of the passed context in order to
 * access to the application assets and resources.
 */
private DataBaseManager() {
    super(ApplicationContextProvider.getContext(), DB_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

    try {
        createDataBase();
        openDataBase();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

/**
 * Singleton for DataBase
 *
 * @return singleton instance
 */
public static DataBaseManager instance() {

    if (sInstance == null) {
        sInstance = new DataBaseManager();
    }
    return sInstance;
}


/**
 * Creates a empty database on the system and rewrites it with your own
 * database.
 *
 * @throws java.io.IOException io exception
 */
private void createDataBase() throws IOException {

    boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

    if (dbExist) {
        // do nothing - database already exist
    } else {

        // By calling this method an empty database will be created into
        // the default system path
        // of your application so we are gonna be able to overwrite that
        // database with our database.
        this.getReadableDatabase();

        try {

            copyDataBase();

        } catch (IOException e) {

            throw new Error("Error copying database");
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each
 * time you open the application.
 *
 * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
 */
private boolean checkDataBase() {

    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

    try {
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
                SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

    } catch (SQLiteException e) {

        // database doesn't exist yet.

    }

    if (checkDB != null) {

        checkDB.close();

    }

    return checkDB != null;
}

/**
 * Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created
 * empty database in the system folder, from where it can be accessed and
 * handled. This is done by transfering bytestream.
 *
 * @throws java.io.IOException io exception
 */
public void copyDataBase() throws IOException {

    // Open your local db as the input stream
    InputStream myInput = ApplicationContextProvider.getContext().getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

    // Path to the just created empty db
    String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

    // Open the empty db as the output stream
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

    // transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }

    // Close the streams
    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();

}

private void openDataBase() throws SQLException {

    // Open the database
    String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    mDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
            SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
}

/**
 * Select method
 *
 * @param query select query
 * @return - Cursor with the results
 * @throws android.database.SQLException sql exception
 */
public Cursor select(String query) throws SQLException {
    return mDataBase.rawQuery(query, null);
}

/**
 * Insert method
 *
 * @param table  - name of the table
 * @param values values to insert
 * @throws android.database.SQLException sql exception
 */
public void insert(String table, ContentValues values) throws SQLException {
    mDataBase.insert(table, null, values);
}

/**
 * Delete method
 *
 * @param table - table name
 * @param where WHERE clause, if pass null, all the rows will be deleted
 * @throws android.database.SQLException sql exception
 */
public void delete(String table, String where) throws SQLException {

    mDataBase.delete(table, where, null);

}

/**
 * Update method
 *
 * @param table  - table name
 * @param values - values to update
 * @param where  - WHERE clause, if pass null, all rows will be updated
 */
public void update(String table, ContentValues values, String where) {

    mDataBase.update(table, values, where, null);

}

/**
 * Let you make a raw query
 *
 * @param command - the sql comand you want to run
 */
public void sqlCommand(String command) {
    mDataBase.execSQL(command);
}

@Override
public synchronized void close() {

    if (mDataBase != null)
        mDataBase.close();

    super.close();

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}
```

}

I managed to upgrade the database but I didn't succeed to persist data in it. Is it possible for this kind of database?

Comment: `SQLiteAssetHelper` can assist you with initially populating a database from an asset, then handling upgrades from there: https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper

Answer (score 1):

Rather than do raw copying, just use SQLite to create/alter new database entities.
Create a string that contains your database changes:

```
private static final String ALTER_TABLE3 =
    "ALTER TABLE exercises ADD COLUMN exscore REAL DEFAULT 0.0";
```

then, when the user fires up the app,

```
 @Override
 public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
     Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
            + newVersion + ". NO data will be destroyed");


     if (oldVersion == version_that_needs_alter_table3) {
         db.execSQL(ALTER_TABLE3);
         // any other work here, such as copying data, manipulating, etc on SQLite
         // data - NOT file data.
        }
     <snip>
 }
```